# npm install via git repo - "not found"

Tags: git, ssh, https, bitbucket

I have this in package.json

```
"dependencies":{
   "cdt-models": "git://gitscm.nabisco.com/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-models.git",
}
```

I run `npm install`, and I get this error:

> ```
> npm ERR! Error while executing: npm ERR! /usr/local/bin/git ls-remote
> -h -t git://gitscm.cisco.com/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-models.git
> ```
>
> npm ERR!  npm ERR! fatal: repository
>   'https://gitscm.cisco.com/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-models.git/'
>   not found npm ERR!  npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

now, I know I can access that git repo from my current machine, because I have the right SSH keys and can push and pull from that repo.

So what might be going wrong here then?

Comment: I also tried this url: `"cdt-models": "git+https://git@gitscm.nabisco.com/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-models.git"` got the same error.

Comment: If I use this url: `https://gitscm.nabisco.com/scm/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-models.git` then `npm install` just hangs forever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although it took a little bit longer than a pure NPM install, this seemed to work:

```
"cdt-models": "git+https://gitscm.nabisco.com/scm/it-gats-cdtechnologyarchitecture-cdtsdaas/cdt-models.git",
```